# Pause jquery ticker on hover and resume on mouse out

Tags: jquery

I have the following code and would like to pause the ticker on mouse over and resume with mouse out, thanks in advance :-)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Initialize the plugin with no custom options
$(document).ready(function () {
    var left = 0;
$(document).ready(function(e){
function tick() {
        left++;
        $(".ticker").css("margin-left", -left + "px");
        setTimeout(tick, 16);
  }

  tick();
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: use `setInterval` and `clearInterval`

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are after?

You can clear the timeout when the hover event is fired with the mouse entering the div and set the timeout again when the mouse leaves the div.

```js
var left = 0;
var timer;

function tick() {
  left++;
  $(".ticker").css("margin-left", -left + "px");
  timer = setTimeout(tick, 16);
}

$(".ticker").hover(

  // This is called when the mouse enters the div
  function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  },
  // This is called when the mouse leaves the div
  function() {
    setTimeout(tick, 16);
  }
);

tick();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ticker" style="text-align: center">Ticker Text</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **clearInterval()** Method to find the solution. Here is a working snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var left = 0;
  var ticker;

  function tick() {
    left++;
    $(".ticker").css("margin-left", left + "px");
    ticker = setTimeout(tick, 16);
  }

  tick();

  $(".ticker").mouseover(function() {
    clearInterval(ticker);
  });

  $(".ticker").mouseout(function() {
    ticker = setTimeout(tick, 16);
  });
});
```

```css
.ticker {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ticker">Demo</div>
```

Hope this is what you want :)

Comment: Sorry about the wrong fiddle link! You can see the demo now!

Answer (score 0):

i created jquery plugin for you

### Jquery:

```
$(function(){
    $.fn.ticker = function(options){
        var defaults = {
            count: 0
        };

        options = $.extend(true,options,defaults);

        var tickerEle = this;
        var tickerInterval;

        var start = function(){
            tickerInterval = setInterval(function(){
                $(tickerEle).text(options.count);
                options.count++;
            },100);
        };

        var stop = function(){
            clearInterval(tickerInterval);
        };
        start();
        $(tickerEle).hover(function(){
            stop();
        },function(){
            start();
        });

        return tickerEle;
    };
}());
```

### html:

```
<span class="tickerCount"></span>

<script>
$(function(){
   $(".tickerCount").ticker();
});
</script>
```

### css:

```
.tickerCount{
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Change code as per your requuirements and [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1h057n7m/1/)